# Moving from a fragment to a new activity

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

I have BottomNavigation and am now in the first snippet. In the first fragment there are two buttons, I need to be thrown to a new activity by pressing these buttons. I do not understand how to implement it correctly. I get an error.

[Code,eror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARlAX.jpg)

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView
            (@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup rootView=null;


        rootView=(ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        return rootView;

        Button button=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), One.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }


        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Click to image please. Android studio offers to delete the method for me and does not give any options.

Comment: `return rootView` should be last line of method . You can read the error by hovering on it .

Comment: Riko, the image does not contain the error. It contains an underscored line which errorred out. But it does not indicate what the error is.

Comment: I put rootView at the end of the method. Now the error: "error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
                return rootView;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `return rootView` at the end of the code block:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

    Button button=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), One.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```